# Detection of accessing on a mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I have a website im developing, and I plan to release a companion app alongside it since it doesnt look nearly as good on mobile as it does on desktop. There are a lot of performance issues as well. Ive noticed that some website notify you to go to a different page if you are using a mobile device, and I want to do something like that, except have a message pop up. Im sure i can handle the message part, but what i need help with is the methodology behind detecting usage of a mobile device. Ive seen this website through a simple google search:

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

but i have absolutely NO idea how to implement it with JS.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: How about making a little search? [Detecting a mobile browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)

Comment: There is a javascript button on detectmobilebrowsers.com that contains the script they're using. It uses regular expression patterns matched against the given browser's user agent string.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
/**
    * Mobile Detect
    * @license    http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php The MIT License
*/
class Mobile_Detect
{
    protected $accept;
    protected $userAgent;
    protected $isMobile = false;
    protected $isAndroid = null;
    protected $isAndroidtablet = null;
    protected $isIphone = null;
    protected $isIpad = null;
    protected $isBlackberry = null;
    protected $isBlackberrytablet = null;
    protected $isOpera = null;
    protected $isPalm = null;
    protected $isWindows = null;
    protected $isWindowsphone = null;
    protected $isGeneric = null;
    protected $devices = array(
    "android" => "android.*mobile",
    "androidtablet" => "android(?!.*mobile)",
    "blackberry" => "blackberry",
    "blackberrytablet" => "rim tablet os",
    "iphone" => "(iphone|ipod)",
    "ipad" => "(ipad)",
    "palm" => "(avantgo|blazer|elaine|hiptop|palm|plucker|xiino)",
    "windows" => "windows ce; (iemobile|ppc|smartphone)",
    "windowsphone" => "windows phone os",
    "generic" => "(kindle|mobile|mmp|midp|pocket|psp|symbian|smartphone|treo|up.browser|up.link|vodafone|wap|opera mini)");

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        $this->accept = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'];

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE']))
        {
            $this->isMobile = true;
        }
        elseif (strpos($this->accept, 'text/vnd.wap.wml') > 0 || strpos($this->accept, 'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml') > 0)
        {
            $this->isMobile = true;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach ($this->devices as $device => $regexp)
            {
                if ($this->isDevice($device))
                {
                    $this->isMobile = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
        * Overloads isAndroid() | isAndroidtablet() | isIphone() | isIpad() | isBlackberry() | isBlackberrytablet() | isPalm() | isWindowsphone() | isWindows() | isGeneric() through isDevice()
        *
        * @param string $name
        * @param array $arguments
        * @return bool
    */
    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        $device = substr($name, 2);
        if ($name == "is" . ucfirst($device) && array_key_exists(strtolower($device), $this->devices))
        {
            return $this->isDevice($device);
        } 
        else
        {
            trigger_error("Method $name not defined", E_USER_WARNING);
        }
    }

    /**
        * Returns true if any type of mobile device detected, including special ones
        * @return bool
    */
    public function isMobile()
    {
        return $this->isMobile;
    }

    protected function isDevice($device)
    {
        $var = "is" . ucfirst($device);
        $return = $this->$var === null ? (bool) preg_match("/" . $this->devices[strtolower($device)] . "/i", $this->userAgent) : $this->$var;
        if ($device != 'generic' && $return == true) {
            $this->isGeneric = false;
        }
        return $return;
    }
}   

   //call this way
    $detect= new Mobile_Detect();
    if ($detect->isMobile())
    {
        $_SESSION['mobile']="mobile";
    }
```